# Numpy: split array into parts according to sequence of values

Tags: python, numpy, split, seq

**What i have** is a big numpy one-dimensional np.int16 array with data and one boolean array, which stores information whether a particular sample (wich is `samplesize` long) of data fits some criteria (is valid) or don't fits (is not valid).
I mean i have something like this:

```
samplesize = 5
data = array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 2, 1, 1], dtype=int16) 
membership = array([False, True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Here `membership[0]` identifies whether `data[ 0*samplesize  : 1*samplesize  ]` is valid.

**What i want** is to split data array into chunks according to sequence of `True` values in membership array. For example, if `membership` contains **three or more** successive `True` statement  then the decision is made, that it is meaningful sample of `data`.

**Example**

```
True, True, True , True - valid sequence 
True, True, False, True , True - invalid sequece
```

**Assuming** we have identified  start of `i`-th valid sequence as `start[i]` and end of such a sequence as `end[i]`, i want to split an `data` array into pieces which start from  `start[i] * samplesize` and last to `end[i] * samplesize`.

How could i accomplish this ?

Comment: What have you already tried with `np.split` and where's your problem?

Comment: I could not use `np.split` because it could only split by the list of known indexes. I need to find edges for splitting by analyzing the `membership` array, and that is the question - how to find these start and end indexes of successive `True` statements.

Comment: I could not also use condition spliting. I thought about `itertools.groupby` but i am curious if there could be more efficient solutions.

Comment: What about applying `np.diff` to `membership`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand your question. Do you want to get start & end index of `membership` with 3 or more  successive True?

Here is the code to do that, the basic idea is to `diff(membership)`, and get the index of rising edge and falling edge:

```
import numpy as np
membership = np.random.randint(0, 2, 100)
d = np.diff(np.r_[0, membership, 0])
start = np.where(d == 1)[0]
end = np.where(d == -1)[0]
mask = (end - start) >= 3
start = start[mask]
end = end[mask]

for s, e in zip(start, end):
    print s, e, membership[s:e]
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that `mask = (end - start) >= 3` is possible. Thanks a lot. I was looking exactly for such a vectorizing calculation approach.